# Why does my assignment to Caption in ClientSockedRead event not have effect?

Tags: delphi

For school we had the project to build a simple memory game using delphi. Now I wanted to add an online multiplayer mode using ClientSockets und ServerSockets. So far I got the connection between the host and the client game working. For a first try I wanted to change the points a player has so I have this in the ClientSocketRead procedure/event:

```
zPunkte[1] := CmdValue;
ShowMessage( IntToStr( CmdValue ) );
lbPunkteSpieler1.Caption := inttostr(zPunkte[1]);
lbPunkteSpieler1.Update;
```

So when the event is fired a messagebox with the content "CmdValue" is displayed, but the Caption of the "lbPunkteSpieler1" label doesn't change. I've tried to change the caption to a fixed value like "test" in the event but this doesn't work either. When I want to change the caption within a ButtonClick event it works correctly.

I hope someone could help me out with this problem ^-^

Comment: Why are you calling `Update`? That's not needed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I found this as a solution for a maybe similar problem, so I tried it out. Removing it doesn't change anything.

Comment: *Removing it doesn't change anything.* That is precisely my point.

Comment: So you mean that it's useless and I should remove it?

Answer (score 0):

The explanations that make most sense are:

1. Something else in your program is changing the label's caption back to its original value.
2. You are trying to change the label's caption from a thread other than the main GUI thread.

If the code in the question is not running on the GUI thread, you need to find a way to marshal that code onto the main thread.

Comment: 1. This shouldn't be the case.
2. I hope I get you right: I have three units, the first unit is created in the beginning and is for the local play mode. It has a button which creates a window where you can choose between Hosting a Online game or joining an existing game. Each of these units has their own objects and procedures. So that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Have a look at the help for `Synchronize`.  This is a simple way to achieve what David has suggested - marshalling the code onto the main thread.

Comment: Here is my Client unit: http://pastebin.com/hDXgHa3h

It's created with:

    `TMemoryClient.Create(Application.MainForm).Show;`

Lines 406 and 309 are the most interesting I think

Comment: That code looks nothing like that in the question. Why don't you do some debugging?